# chirp on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, tty, ham-radio, chirp

I did install the `chirp` on my `ubuntu 14.04 lts` according to instructions:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dansmith/chirp-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chirp-daily
```

It worked. How do I run it?

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , chirp is available though Ubuntu's repositories so you didn't need to add that one, unless you wanted newest version. I'll install chirp in a minute, see what i can do

Answer (score 1):

Try running "chirpw" in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Having installed `chirp` using `sudo apt-get install chirp` , I can see that there is `chirpw` command available in terminal, as well as `/usr/share/applications/chirp.desktop` file. Thus you can either run `chirpw` in terminal, or search for the `chirp` in Unity's Dash

Answer (score 0):

As you know, CHIRP is a FREE cross-platform, cross-radio programming tool. It works on Windows and Linux (and MacOSX with a little work). It supports a growing list of radios across several manufacturers and allows transferring of memory contents between them.

chirp is [available in the Universe repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chirp&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

The first thing you need to do is [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for your version of Ubuntu.

Then open a terminal and enter the following command:

`sudo apt-get install chirp`

or Install via Ubuntu Software.

Then launch either via the Chirp icon in your application launcher:

[image]

Or via terminal with the command: `chirpw`